# Guess the random number game

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am making a number guessing game and I do not know how to incorporate a certain number of guesses the users has to get the correct answer. I want the user to have only 3 guesses to guess the number but after 3 guesses, they lose if they do NOT get it correct. Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
srand ( time(NULL) );

cout << "Select a difficulty: 1) Easy, 2) Medium, 3) Hard " << endl;
int userlevel;
int userinput;
int randomNumber;
cin >> userlevel;
{
if (userlevel==1)
  cout << "You chose Easy: 3 chances to guess correctly" << endl;
  cout << "Pick a number between 1 and 10: " << endl;

  cin >> userinput;
  randomNumber = rand() % 10 + 1;

  if (randomNumber==userinput)
    cout << "You, guessed correctly! You win!" << endl;
  else
    cout << "I'm sorry, that is not correct. You lose." << endl;
}


{

  if (userlevel==2)
   cout << "You chose Medium: 4 chanaces to guess correctly" << endl;
   cout << "Pick a number between 1 and 50: " << endl;

     cin >> userinput;
     randomNumber = rand() % 50 + 1;

   if (randomNumber==userinput)
     cout << "You, guessed correctly! You win!" << endl;
   else
    cout << "I'm sorry, that is not correct. You lose." << endl;
  }


   {
    if (userlevel==3)
     cout << "You chose Hard: 5 chances to guess correctly" << endl;
     cout << "Pick a number between 1 and 100: " << endl;

     cin >> userinput;
     randomNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;

  if (randomNumber==userinput)
       cout << "You, guessed correctly! You win!" << endl;
     else
       cout << "I'm sorry, that is not correct. You lose." << endl;

 }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: a loop with a terminating condition.....

Comment: You should look to see how you could write a single function that encodes all three blocks of code.  You'd pass arguments to identify the level name, the number of guesses allowed, and the maximum value in the range.  This ends up saving you writing.

Comment: What's going on with these brackets `{` preceding the `if`s ?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into while-loops. It would be used like this:

```
    int main() {
    //...everything above this in yours is good

    int Number_to_guess = (rand() % 10 + 1);
    int NChances = userlevel + 2;

    cout << "You have " << NChances << " chances to guess right.\n";
    while (NChances != 0)
    {
        cout << "Guess: ";
        cin >> userinput;
        if (userinput == Number_to_Guess) {
            cout << "You win! Congrats!\n";
            break; // this will break out of the while-loop
        }

        NChances--; // this will count down the chances left
    }

    if (NChances == 0) {
        cout << "Sorry, you lose. Try again next time!\n";
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main think you're missing here is a loop around the guess limit. So after you figure out what level they are, you can say something like the following pseudocode:

```
While (counter <= 3)
*Your If Statements*
counter = counter +1
```

Make sure that in the if statement where they guessed the number right, you break them out of the loop early.

Finally, it might make more sense to guess a number before you enter the loop. So, something like they pick the difficulty, the random number is picked depending on what they say, and then the loop begins. The way it is now, a new random number will be created each time through the loop. I'm not sure if that's intended.